# SUM based on different Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT 
    ISNULL(DrugName,'Sub Total:') as Drug, 
    SUM(COUNT) as Count, 
    Percentage
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT 
        DrugName, 
        DrugCategoryName,
         COUNT(*) as Count,
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()) as Percentage
      FROM 
        Visit V 
    INNER JOIN Drug D on
        V.DrugID = D.DrugID 
    INNER JOIN DrugCategory DC on 
        D.DrugCategoryID = DC.DrugCategoryID
     GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
        ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName))
 ) a
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
    ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName, Percentage), (DrugCategoryName))
```

which gives the following results:

```
 Drug                            Count  Percentage
 Amphetamines                    401    4.24
 Benzodiazapine                  435    4.60
 Biodone                         459    4.85
 Sub Total:                      1295   NULL
 Brown Heroin                    436    4.61
 Buprenorphine                   396    4.18
 Cocaine                         444    4.69
 Did not inject                  404    4.27
 Endone                          450    4.75
 Fentanyl Patch                  404    4.27
 Heroin                          1365   14.42
 Heroin & Cocaine                448    4.73
 Ice/Crystal/Meth                889    9.39
 Sub Total:                      5236   NULL
 Kapanol                         427    4.51
 Methadone                       430    4.54
 Methadone Syrup                 394    4.16
 Morphine                        417    4.41
 MS Contin                       438    4.63
 MS Mono                         424    4.48
 Other Amphetamines              404    4.27
 Sub Total:                      2934   NULL
```

What I'm needing to do also is calculate the Sub Total Percentages, so for example the first Sub Total is 1295 so that would calculate a percentage based off 1295 + 5236 + 2934 and get a value of 13.68%, and so on for the other Sub Total rows.

How could this be done dynamically so no matter the amount of Sub Totals it will calculate it correctly?

Comment: have you tried doing SELECT 
    ISNULL(DrugName,'Sub Total:') as Drug, 
    SUM(COUNT) as Count, 
    SUM(Percentage) / SUM(COUNT)  AS perc...   then all as before

Comment: Yes i have thanks @Cato - no good.

Comment: You're going to need an `order by DrugCategoryName` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT 
    ISNULL(DrugName,'Sub Total:') as Drug, 
    SUM(COUNT) as Count, 
    Percentage
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT 
        DrugName, 
        DrugCategoryName,
         COUNT(*) as Count,
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()) as Percentage
      FROM 
        Visit V 
    INNER JOIN Drug D on
        V.DrugID = D.DrugID 
    INNER JOIN DrugCategory DC on 
        D.DrugCategoryID = DC.DrugCategoryID
     GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
        ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName))
 ) a
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
    ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName, Percentage), (DrugCategoryName)))

      SELECT [DRUG],[COUNT] ,ISNULL([PERCENTAGE],([COUNT]/S)*100) AS [PERCENTAGE] FROM CTE A CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT CAST(SUM([COUNT])AS NUMERIC(22,6)) AS S  FROM CTE B WHERE DRUG='SUB TOTAL:')C
```

OUTPUT

```
DRUG    COUNT   PERCENTAGE
Amphetamines    401 4.240000
Benzodiazapine  435 4.600000
Biodone 459 4.850000
Sub Total:  1295    13.681986
Brown Heroin    436 4.610000
Buprenorphine   396 4.180000
Cocaine 444 4.690000
Did not inject  404 4.270000
Endone  450 4.750000
Fentanyl Patch  404 4.270000
Heroin  1365    14.420000
Heroin & Cocaine    448 4.730000
Ice/Crystal/Meth    889 9.390000
Sub Total:  5236    55.319599
Kapanol 427 4.510000
Methadone   430 4.540000
Methadone Syrup 394 4.160000
Morphine    417 4.410000
MS Contin   438 4.630000
MS Mono 424 4.480000
Other Amphetamines  404 4.270000
Sub Total:  2934    30.998415
```

Comment: Thanks @Chanukya, that looks to have worked well, but possible to incorporate that into the original query?

Comment: @James from my understanding please put your result cte and after that you can use as i did

Comment: Fair enough. I'd like to see if that's avoidable ideally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just calculate the total in the subquery and divide:

```
SELECT COALESCE(DrugName, 'Sub Total:') as Drug, 
       SUM(COUNT) as Count, 
       SUM(COUNT) / total_cnt as Percentage
FROM (SELECT DrugName, DrugCategoryName,
             COUNT(*) as Count,
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), COUNT(*)) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) over () as Percentage,
             SUM(1.0*COUNT(*)) OVER () as total_cnt
      FROM Visit V INNER JOIN  
           Drug D 
           ON V.DrugID = D.DrugID INNER JOIN
           DrugCategory DC 
           ON D.DrugCategoryID = DC.DrugCategoryID
      GROUP BY DrugName, DrugCategoryName
     ) vd
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName, Percentage, Total_cnt),
                        (DrugCategoryName, Total_Cnt))
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. It errors though unfortunately:

Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I was able to get it to work: http://rextester.com/FEZT88753

Comment: @shawnt00 - when I try your example the Percentage column is 0? Using an MSDN SQL Azure instance.

Comment: The purpose of the multiplication by 1.0 is to convert the result to a decimal value so that it won't use integer division. Did you leave that part in? Obviously you didn't purpose any actual data to test with and apparently the error you reported went away.

Comment: Current query is failing with the following error. 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

I can post some actual data if that would help.